# What are the best resources for SharePoint 2010 development?

Tags: development

What are the best resources for SharePoint 2010 development? Please do one answer per answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with community site: [SharePoint Dev Wiki v2010.](http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/sp2010/SharePoint+2010+Development+Home)

Answer (score 2):

You're on it!

A little tongue in cheek perhaps.  But you cannot beat a direct answer to a direct question.  Plus if people don't know they might be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the [MSDN SharePoint Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/default.aspx). Documentation is already almost in parity with the documentation of previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

I've ploughed through all the session videos from SharePoint Conference. Alot of gems hidden away there! http://www.mssharepointconference.com

Answer (score 1):

[Twitter](http://www.twitter.com), don't forget about Twitter. Follow interesting SharePoint Tweeps and the [#SharePoint](http://twitter.com/#search?q=%23sharepoint) hashtag

Answer (score 0):

Channel9 contains alot of cutting edge videos on [SP2010](http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/sharepoint-2010/) and [VS2010](http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/Visual+Studio+2010/). I follow their feed on [twitter](http://twitter.com/ch9) and [RSS](http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/sharepoint-2010/RSS/).

Answer (score 0):

I would say Google or Bing! Since there are so many people blogging about so many different topics, and often the information I'm looking for is not part of the standard documentation, I think the web in general, all tied together with a good search engine makes the best resource!!

Comment: don't agree there -- the question isn't "where can I resources" but "where can I find good resources"...

Answer (score 0):

I have written a range of blog posts about [moving a WSPBuilder solution from SharePoint 2007 to 2010](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2010/03/porting-sharepoint-2007-wspbuilder.html).

Quite insightful if you have experience with SharePoint 2007 development.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN [Getting started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee513147.aspx) ressource